# Javascript: keydown event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

I am writing a userscript with the following code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener("keydown", arrows, false);
    function arrows(e) {
        debugger;
        switch(e.keycode) {
             case 37: alert("Left"); break;
             case 39: alert("Right"); break;
        }
    }
})();
```

Eventually the left and right cases will navigate to the previous and next articles in a series, respectively, with something like:

```
window.location = String(parseInt(window.location.href.match(/\d+$/))-1);
```

However, pressing the arrow keys does not cause an alert. The script is clearly loaded, the Chrome developer menu shows the `arrows()` function is registered as an event listener for `window.keydown`, and yet the function never fires. I added `debugger;` to the `arrows()` function, but the debugger does not show when I press the arrow keys.

Comment: Is there an event handler lower in the tree stopping propagation of the `keydown` event (in which case you should set the third parameter of `addEventListener` to `true` to enable capturing)?

Answer (score 12):

The [event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) is  probably getting stopped at some point on the handler for an element, before it bubbles up to `window` (probably due to a poorly-written `onkeydown` returning `false` to prevent the default action, not caring that this also stops propagation).

You should attach your listener with *capturing*, so that it will capture the event at `window`, *before* it bubbles:

```
// note the third parameter
window.addEventListener("keydown", arrows, true);
```

Comment: The key seems to be adding the listener to `window` rather than to the `body` or a `div` element.

Answer (score 1):

You have mispelled the keyCode:

```
switch(e.keyCode) { // Code is uppercase
    case 37: alert("Left"); break;
    case 39: alert("Right"); break;
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't stop the `debugger` statement from firing, though.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley huh?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan See line 5 of the code in the OP. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Answer (score 0):

Your events might be being caught as expected. Use `console.log` instead of `alert` to validate that event got caught. Reasons why it does not work with `alert` are unknown for me: I suspect it has something to do with event fire timing and alert dialogs stopping normal workflow